# Does it make sense to use static variables in the main function in C?

Tags: c, function, static, program-entry-point

As far as my current understanding of the 'static' keyword goes, it prevents a variable from being re-initialized AND it prevents the variable from leaving the memory when a function ends.

In C, I usually use this when a variable doesn't need to be global, but also shouldn't change in between function calls. (f.i. microcontroller interrupts)

Now, in some C code for an STM32, I saw the following:

```
int main(void)
{
  static char buffer[CONSOLEBUFFERSIZE];
  ...
```

To me, this doesn't make sense. This variable is used to buffer incoming commands in order to process them when the termination character is received. But the two properties of 'static' I described earlier do not apply to the main function because main() is called only once and 'never' ends. So my actual question:

Could this be using some hocus-pocus that I don't know about or would it simply be copied code from an interrupt or other function and did the programmers forget or not bother to remove the static keyword?

Comment: if CONSOLEBUFFERSIZE is Very Large, stack may over flow, so use static is safe.

Comment: A C compiler is not obligated to put variables of `main()` in the "stack" space.  Thus using `static` to move a variable from the "stack" to the "data" segment is compiler implementation dependent.  `static` may change the segment as suggested by some answers.  It also may have no effect.

Answer (score 12):

One difference is, that static variables usually use the program's data segment instead of stack. Maybe that's the reason for declaring `buffer` as `static` (especially if `CONSOLEBUFFERSIZE` is large).

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense. I don't know what the stack boundaries are for this system but 64 bytes of permanent allocation on your stack sounds like something you want to avoid. It sure helps preventing stack overflow.

(64 is the current value of CONSOLEBUFFERSIZE)

Answer (score 3):

On some systems the stack is a fixed, limited size.  In these cases `static` is useful simply to move the buffer out of the stack and put it somewhere where the linker has been set up to allocate more space.

It would also be possible to re-configure the linker to offer a larger initial stack, but `static` is easier and still does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you make a c project with many files and mains for them then its value wont change....

Comment: That's if it was a global variable, then you'd be free to extern it in other files and use it...